# SQL query for this operation?

Tags: sql

[image]

Can someone please help me with this SQL query? I used a GROUP BY Category but how can I list the top two of revenue?

So i am using the following query for now --
SELECT Product
FROM table_name
ORDER BY Revenue DESC,
GROUP BY Category,
LIMIT 2;

Please let me know if this would work?

Comment: provide text instead of image

Comment: I just have a snip, can you please just use the snip?

Comment: SELECT Product
FROM table_name 
ORDER BY Revenue DESC,
GROUP BY Category,
LIMIT 2;

Will this work?

Comment: For what DBMS is this intended - MySQL / MSSQL / Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `row_number` as follows

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT product,
              category,
              Sum(revenue) as sales,
              Row_number()
                OVER(
                  partition BY category
                  ORDER BY  sum([Sales]) desc) AS RowNum
       FROM   table
       GROUP  BY product,
                 category) a
WHERE  rownum IN ( 1, 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports dense rank:

```
Select * 
from 
  (Select tbl.*,
          Dense_rank() over (partition by category order by revenue desc) as rnk
   From yourtable TBL
) Tbl2
Where tbl2.rnk<=2
```